# Pom.xml throws Missing artifact error for org.springframework.security.extentions continously

Tags: maven, single-sign-on

Below is a small part my pom.xml for SSO using SAML,

```
<properties>
<SAML-version>1.0.0-RC2-SNAPSHOT</SAML-version>
</properties>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
<version>${SAML-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

for which STS(spring tool suite 3.1) throws below error continuosly,

```
"Missing artifact org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-   core:jar:1.0.0-RC2-SNAPSHOT".
```

I navigated to maven repo and i can find the jar downloaded by maven.

Kindly help me.

Thanks,Selva

Comment: Remove .cache folder in your local maven repo, and retry.

Comment: Comment from user14269686 seems to be the correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add This

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.springsource.org</id>
        <name>repo.springsource.org-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Instead I Installed spring-security-saml2-core.jar in my repo using mvn install command . It worked

Answer (score 4):

The [Spring Security SAML website](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) is currently incorrect.. The groupId should actually be `org.springframework.security.extensions` instead of just `org.springframework.security`.

The below dependency configuration works for me:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```